# How to fix "row in csv_reader" not working?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I'm reading a two column .csv file of variable length. I have some code written that should be able to read the data bar the first line into an x Data column and a y Data column. Here is the code:

```
def csvReader(filename):
with open(filename) as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter = ',')
    rowCount = sum(1 for row in csvReader)
    xData = np.zeros(rowCount)
    yData = np.zeros(rowCount)
    line_count = 0
    firstLine = True

    for row in csvReader:
        print(row)
        if firstLine:
            firstLine = False
            continue
        xData[line_count] = row[0]
        yData[line_count] = row[1]
        line_count += 1
    return xData,yData
```

It outputs an array of zeros, and the console never shows any printed output, which seems to imply that the entire for loop is getting skipped. Any help on this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: You're iterating over all the lines when you do `sum(1 for row in csvReader)` so there are no more lines to read in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

You're exhausting the iterator when you do

```
rowCount = sum(1 for row in csvReader)
```

You need to rewind the file to read it again.

```
csvFile.seek(0)
```